# GuestEntries plugin problem.

Tags: plugins, plugin-guestentries

So I just installed the GuestEntries Plugin. 
Whenever I submit the form, I get

"POST param “sectionId” doesn’t exist"

```
      <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        {{ getCsrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="guestEntries/saveEntry">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="success">
        <input type="hidden" name="opiniones" value="3">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input id="title" type="text" name="title">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea id="body" name="fields[body]"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

-opiniones is the section id.

-Have the section allowed for guest posts, with a user selected.

-Only other plugin Im using is the contact form 1.81

-running Craft CMS 2.6.2964 Personal

Any one can give me hand.?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin is expecting the POST parameter to be `sectionId` rather than `opiniones`. Changing the `name` attribute on that hidden input to `sectionId` should fix your issue.

The other requirements when creating entries from front-end template using *Guest Entries* are outlined below.

Make sure *Allow guest submissions?* is checked in the plugin’s settings (example.com/admin/settings/plugins/guestentries) and set a default author for the section entries will be saved to.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="3">
```

The value for `sectionId` can be determined by going to section settings in the control panel (example.com/admin/settings/sections) and clicking the name of the section you want to use *Guest Entries* with. The section’s ID is the last segment of the URL (e.g example.com/admin/settings/sections/3)

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="success">
```

The value for `redirect` is where a visitor will be redirected upon a successful submission and should be a valid path or URL.

A form field should be added for each field you want to save content to. Be sure to include any fields marked required on the entry type’s settings page (example.com/admin/settings/sections/3/entrytypes/3).

```
<input type="text" name="title">
```

`title` will always be the value for the name attribute for the entry’s title regardless of what *Title Field Label* is set to for the entry type in the control panel.

```
<textarea name="fields[body]"></textarea>
```

Custom fields will use `fields[customFieldHandle]` as the value for the name attribute.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. 

Just realized this as I read your response. Had changed it because of my initial problem, thought it had to be named as the section id... 
SO...

I have the default form from the documentation. doesn't give me the error anymore, but after submit, redirects me to a 404 page, nothing gets posted.
I am not logged in by the way. 

Thanks

Comment: @fidel — On the settings page for the Guest Entries plugin (example.com/admin/settings/plugins/guestentries), make sure _Allow guest submissions?_ is checked and you have a default author assigned to the section you are submitting to. The redirect param ("success") is the path  a successful submission is redirected to, so update that to a valid path and it should address the 404.

Comment: Settings are all good. Is there anything specific on the success page.? Would not having one stop the form from posting.?   Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting, I copied your form into a template and installed the plugin and it worked for me after changing the parameter name for sectionId and setting a default author in the plugin settings on the section. Is 3 the ID for the section you are working with (you can find the section ID in the URL for that section in settings)? Do you have any fields marked as required on that section you aren't including in the submission?

Comment: Cant find where to get the section id... I will have to do a little research and figure that out first. That may be the issue. 
Also, I didn't have that section with its own url, though that might be it, maybe its a combination of that and wrong id.

Comment: You can get the section id here: https://example.com/admin/settings/sections. If you click on the section you want to use Guest Entries with it will add a number to the end of the URL (e.g https://example.com/admin/settings/sections/14)

Comment: OK, so I got the section ID, was incorrect. I put the correct one, replacing 3. 
I don't get the 404 anymore, reloads the main page. But I still have nothing posting. 
For the fields.. one is the "title", the other is 
<textarea id="body" name="fields[body]"></textarea>
Should I be replacing the with the name of my fields.?

title = nombre

textarea=opinion.

Comment: Wait. I think I got it.. 
Not sure what I did honestly, but just got something posted......
It was defiantly the section ID.. 
Stephen.. THANK YOU!! way to stick it out! lol appreciate the help.

Comment: @fidel Glad that worked. You will always use 'title' as the name for that input regardless of what it is labelled in the CP. Custom fields will use 'fields[customFieldHandle]' as the value for the name attribute. I'll edit my answer to include these additional steps towards getting it working.